# I don't have the ssh-copy-id command (windows client)

Tags: server, ssh, vps, hosting

I'm following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) to set up an RSA key pair with my VPS.

I'm using my Windows PC to follow through with the first part of the guide, and `ssh-copy-id` does not exist in the command prompt (neither does `cat`) - meaning I can't send the public key to the server.

Am I doing it wrong? Is it because I'm using Windows?

Comment: If you are using MS Windows, I'm sorry but you'll have to ask on a Windows forum (or on the DigitalOcean forum). Many people here won't be able to help you. BTW, take a look [at this question on Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/224810/is-there-an-equivalent-to-ssh-copy-id-for-windows).

Comment: Oh, okay, I thought that it was relevant because the VPS is running Ubuntu. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With putty, you can upload public key manually, assuming you now can access the server with username and password:

1. Generate the key file, with the guide you followed it will be .pub file, the content of the file should shart with "ssh-rsa AAAA ...."
2. Login to the server machine
3. Copy the content of the .pub file into the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file (for this use vim, nano or your favourite text editor)

If your SSH directory does not exist, create it and then copy the pub file into the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 0644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
...
```

Now you should be able to login with your private key file.

Comment: to copy the file, I suggest ou use winscp ;)